# ETag on load, not only on reload

Tags: perl, caching, etag, mason

I'm trying to set an ETag on an image for tracking with Perl/Mason.

First a created etag.m:

```
<%init>

    warn "Start ETag";
    my $request_header = $r->headers_in();
    my $etag = $request_header->{'If-None-Match'};
    warn "Trace Etag: $request_header->{'If-None-Match'}";

    unless ($etag) {
        warn "Set Etag";
        $r->status(302);
        $r->headers_out->{'Location'} = "/images/etag.gif";
        $r->headers_out->{'Cache-Control'} = 'public';
        $r->headers_out->{'ETag'} = $user->{uid};
        my $gmt_mtime = HTTP::Date::time2str(time());
        $r->headers_out->{'Last-Modified'} = $gmt_mtime;
    }

</%init>
```

I'm using this in another file test_etag.m:

```
<img src="etag.m">
```

On the first call of test_etag.m after clearing the cache I can see the warnings, the etag is empty. Every next call, a can't see any warning so I think the image is cached. Only when I do a reload F5 the correkt ETag will be found and display in the warning.

How can I get the ETag, that was set the first time on every load, not only on reload?

Comment: Is this using the [`Apache`](https://metacpan.org/module/Apache) module?